# Division By Zero in top tag causing Infinite percentage

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Just noticed the following in [this poor soul's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3707515/soul-prisoner):

> [image]

1/0 = Infinity indeed, but I believe it should show more user friendly data e.g. 0 or N/A.

Comment: I must be having a senior moment, but how would the ratio of posts to score (if that's the computation) give a meaningful indication?  I could rationalize the score divided by posts as being an "average" score per post, but the reciprocal doesn't seem to have an easily articulated sense.

Comment: @hardmath hmm.... good point, not sure what this percentage *should* be, maybe worth a new question... :)

Comment: Comparing to my page, the figure 57% is shown, hovering over which repeats the information that I have 90 non-wiki answers with a total score (net upvotes?) of 194 (for my top tag).  But dividing 90/194 gives approx. 46%, not 57%.   I'll try to see if this has already been explained somewhere amongst the redesign announcements.

Comment: Cheers @hardmath and feel free to start question asking what it is if you don't find - easy MSE rep. :-D

Comment: I'd rather see that percentage as, "Top 2% of users in this tag" if anything.  I can't imagine any other measurement would be interesting, nevermind relevant or useful...

Comment: Be happy it is not *Infinity... and Beyond.*

Comment: @hardmath mystery solved, see Oded's answer... :-)

Comment: @Adam sounds like a valid feature request! If and when you start one, let me know. :)

Comment: @rene this, or Infinite Recursion... ;-D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's supposed to be the %age of answers from the total posts (i.e. questions *and* answers).

Given that usually a person would have a post in a tag in order for it to show up, this is... rare. I blame caching.

Anyhow, fixed in the next build.

Comment: Lots of questions by new users are deleted on Stack Overflow every day, leaving those poor souls without any total posts, but with temporary tag score, so not sure it's so rare. Thanks for the quick fix! :)