# Why is the Community user's reach infinity?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-user, people-reached

Why does the [Community user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) have infinity in its "reached" section? It's definitely not a number.

This is how it looks like:

[image: screenshot showing infinity symbol for the "reached" data of Community user]

Comment: Looks like this changed on October 13th 2023. [Snapshot 2023-10-13 01:05:58](https://web.archive.org/web/20231013010558/https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) vs [Snapshot 2023-10-13 20:45:47](https://web.archive.org/web/20231013204547/https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) (looking at SO instead of MSE since it has more captures).

Comment: Just a bit of fun I imagine. It's not completely banned here you know.

Comment: @Brian61354270 It was right that time that the team started restricting access to the Community user's activity subpage, as can be seen in the crawls. I'm assuming that the queries to generate statistics about the Community user were timing out, so the team restricted access and hardcoded the infinity as an Easter egg.

Comment: Though we do [hate it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: fyi: community has [three posts on MSE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1817822): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296077/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336174/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384752/997587

Comment: Might also be a bug, i.e. actual calculation resulting in Infinity e.g. divide by zero. Added the tag just in case. (You can see example of such actual bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258709/division-by-zero-in-top-tag-causing-infinite-percentage))

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Given that the algorithm to calculate people reached [doesn't use division](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here), that's most definitely not the case. Also, the [tag:support] tag is the right tag for cases where you're not sure if something's a bug ([tag:possible-bug] is a synonym).

Comment: @Sonic well division by zero is just example, might also pass some "soft limit" in the code, i.e. there's a sanity check. As for using the support tag for bugs (possible or not), I disagree with this usage, but that's for a different discussion, not here.

Comment: It reached infinity and is on its way to go beyond ...

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda 100% by design.

Comment: @Brian61354270 The October That Never Ended?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is definitely not a bug.

You can probably put the story together about what data is associated with the community user, and the load this might place on its/their profile page - a [Jon Skeet problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227605/165455), but worse - using:

- [Sonic's comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396553/why-is-the-community-users-reach-infinity#comment1326391_396553);
- [this comment from John Wright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383460/confusion-around-the-purpose-of-the-community-user#comment1279078_383464);
- [this sort-of-related answer from Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394721/165455); and,
- [this comment from Andy Mallon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384482/loading-the-community-users-all-actions-subtab-here-on-meta-se-leads-to-a-ser#comment1309071_384482).

Most *internal* Jon Skeet problems - where we have performance issues exposed by hitting "numbers of things" or "sizes of things" thresholds for the first time - have been solved by combinations of denormalizing, pre-aggregating, query tuning, aggressive indexing, and moving expensive queries to readable secondaries.

Of course, the most efficient query is the one you don't have to run at all.

Last year, after seeing a few timeouts on the Community User's profile page, I said to [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear):

> [image]
> This data is useless and really expensive, because it leads to complete scans of several growing tables.
> Since Community is supposed to be a bot, and since a lot of these things they “did” are reassigned activity from deleted users, should we just put N/A for a lot of this?

This was after a fix had been implemented to stop calculating reach; however, the other queries were still expensive.

In October, a PR appeared, with this description:

> As time goes by, we're hitting performance issues with parts of the Community user's profile since it's our catch-all "if we don't know what to do with a bit of data, let's attach it to Community". [...] since none of the data for Community on public is actually valuable, the most expedient thing to do is to just not show it.
> So, that's this PR. Specifically, we are hiding:
> • the Activity, Mod Dashboard, and Settings tabs
> • parts of the Profile tab that have to do with tag stats or posts (keeping badges because I like the idea of Community having [Not a Robot] on SO)
> • any attempt at the "people reached" calculation

As for the infinity symbol, a reviewer of the PR said:

> That's a whole lot of people!  Feels a bit odd. I've got no suggestions for a better thing to display here though

And Adam responded with:

> Oh, it's definitely odd. But I find it mildly amusing, so I'm going with it and subjecting everyone to my sense of "humor"

[image: "To ∞ and beyond!"]

Comment: "a wild PR has appeared"! But, who submitted that wonderful pull request? ;)

Comment: Can we just halt this? It's more than enough.

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by "this." Or "we," for that matter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's just that this answer is MORE than satisfactory.

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear I see. Well, most people seem to enjoy detail, the behind-the-scenes humor around a change, and the fun aspects like photoshopping Adam's head onto Buzz Lightyear's body. It's not for everyone. But I would argue that having a profile page for a background process is fun and humorous in the first place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Me too, I guess. Anyways, I won't talk in this thread anymore because extended discussions on Stack Exchange are _discouraged_, unless we go to chat, but I am not doing that.

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear Blame the "meta effect". Ref. [What is the "meta effect"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/289691) [tag:faq].

Comment: @AaronBertrand well now that we got Adam in a suit, you're next! ;-)

Comment: It would have been nicer if following the old links to its removed pages would display an error message saying that access to those pages has been removed and why. I used to use its activity list for various reasons, mostly to track anonymous edits, "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" reviews, and uses of the *Share feedback* button in review queues. It was also a useful page for me back when I was active here making anonymous edits (see link in my profile). I understand that database access can be a limiting factor, but it broke my workflow.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I agree that some of this data should be made available but perhaps through other avenues? 10k or 20k tools could get anonymous edits, for example. Review queues could get a link for recent completed reviews too (eg to show Improve/Reject and Edit stats). (Also, every change [breaks someone's workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/))

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not complaining about the removal; just the lack of communication around the removal. As an example, [here's an email I received from another service when a feature I used was considered a bug and fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVsKO.png).

Comment: @Sonic To be fair, Prezi _detected your workflow_. I have never considered this workflow and I don't know how we could have discovered that you used it. All the comments here about the community user's profile page have been about performance or UI oddities (like setting their profile to use dark mode). I'm sorry that our focus was on performance and not seeking out workflows that made use of the profile page of a background process.

Comment: @Sonic We can't make a meta post for every line of code we change. Well, we could, but then we wouldn't have time to change any code. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand *I don't know how we could have discovered that you used [this workflow]*...a quick tag search would have revealed a [recent bug report on it that I filed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384482/loading-the-community-users-all-actions-subtab-here-on-meta-se-leads-to-a-ser). Also, I wasn't asking for a meta post - like I said, an error message when attempting to access the tab would have worked, as would, e.g., an edit to the recent feature changes post.

Comment: @Sonic I did review that one, and considered that not really even a bug, but a result of the underlying performance issue (leading to a timeout), and something discovered just by looking around. Not that it was a critical part of anyone's workflow. Or that anyone here considered it a "feature change" worthy of announcement (meta post or not).

Comment: @Sonic Where was [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384482/loading-the-community-users-all-actions-subtab-here-on-meta-se-leads-to-a-ser#comment1309072_384482) announced? Like this one, in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371897/165455) to a post by someone who noticed the change. This post was probably overlooked in review because of the `status-bydesign` tag. In any case, I now kind of regret offering any info at all.

Comment: Okay, yeah, to be fair, most likely I would have been the only one standing to benefit from an announcement. However, still, an error message to those who tried to access a removed page would have been beneficial, going directly to those who actually try to use it. Better yet, that would be part of the code change, so no extra time not writing code is used.

Comment: As an aside: It would be great if SE sites had a public changelist *somewhere*, containing each line item that was pushed in the latest (and previous) builds. It would give us community members a place to check for situations like this (and update our own Metas with answers or [status-*] tags!) without having to rely on direct Staff/CM involvement.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I find it funny, and I'm always glad to hear fun stories like this from behind the scenes :-)

Comment: I second that, I don't really understand what is to complain here. It was a fun (and at the same time informative) read, please continue with those kind of insights! Not everyone hates fun here ;)